# How to pass multiple values to query dynamically in android?

Tags: android

In my project I have to select multiple values and pass it to a query. i.e page1 contains checkboxes. I am storing the selected checkbox id's into an array.
I am shuffling that array and getting the values randomly. Now I need to pass these random values to a query. Using IN operator in database I can pass the values 
statically but how can I pass the values dynamcially to the query.

For ex:(Passing values statically)

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE person_id IN ('21','22')
```

In the above query the id's 21 and 22 are know previously and so we are passing statically but I want to send the values to query dynamically.

```
Page1:
public static ArrayList<String> chksublist = new ArrayList<String>();

Page2:
 Collections.shuffle(chksublist );
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE person_id IN ('21','22')
In the above line I want to send the random values which are in chksublist array.
```

Comment: Build your query string using e.g. `TextUtils.join`. What's the point of shuffling the array before sending it to the SQL query?

Comment: check this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String query = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE person_id IN  (" + TextUtils.join(",", chksublist) + ")";`

But shuffling the `chksublist` before sending it to your SQL query has no impact on the result set you get from SQL. It will not randomly permute your results. Remove `Collections.shuffle(chksublist);` and use

`String query = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE person_id IN  (" + TextUtils.join(",", chksublist) + ") ORDER BY RANDOM()";`

Answer (score 1):

see how values are dynamicaly passed

```
  // Getting single contact
 public Contact getContact(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

 // here   new String[] { String.valueOf(id) } value is added dynamicaly which is passed to the function
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
// return contact
return contact;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your query like this

```
int values[];      //it contains your generated values like 21,22....
String query="SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE person_id IN (";

for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
query=query+"'"+values[i]+"'";
if(i<values.length-1){
query=query+",";    //No , after last values
} 

}
query+=")";
```

finally pass this query.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply...I kept like String query="SELECT c.* FROM table1 c, table2 q WHERE c.cid = q.cid AND c.id IN (";

      for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(un);i++){
      query=query+"'"+chksublist.get(i)+"'";
      if(i<(chksublist.size()-1)){
      query=query+",";  
      } 

      }
      query+=")"+"AND q.choicetoselect = 1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + un + "";  but it is showing error in the query..plz help me where i went wrong

Comment: First try to run your full query statically.Then build similar string.Also You can check by printing your final query to see what went wrong.

Comment: Excellent Work @Rasel. Thank a ton. Saved me an couple of hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
cursor = database.query(tablename,
                    new String[] {"TopName"}, "id IN(?,?)", new String[]{"2","3"}, null, null, null);
```

using raw query

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE person_id IN ("+parameter1+","+parameter2+")";
db.rawQuery(query);
```